# I can't install window 10: 0x8007025D probem

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation

I can't manage to install window 10 here is what happened in order.

First I tried to put my window 10 disk content on an USB key using this tutorial :
[Install Windows from a USB Flash Drive | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/install-windows-from-a-usb-flash-drive)

I then tried to install it but it failed at around 68%. It was either this error message.

Windows Cannot Install Required Files *0x8007025D*
or with the code *0xc0000005*

I then tried the solution with Media Creation Tool with similar result, even if now it seem that it stop at 30%.

I made a test with [memtest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) and it say that my ram is fine.

Now, I have tried the solution to unplug one of my 2 hard drive, with one hard drive I clean it using diskpart here what happen.

When I clean it the installation stop at 30% and this happen *0xc0000005*
after that it create partition, and again this one at 30%.

Windows Cannot Install Required Files *0x8007025D*

Keep in mind, my memtest find no problem and I have a perfectly legal window 10 copy.

Any Idea for this specific problem?

Comment: https://appuals.com/windows-cannot-install-required-files-0x8007025d/

Comment: If error still persists, boot from the installation media, choose Repair the computer and choose commands prompts. Use copy commands to find out setupact.log and setuperr.log under: c:\$windows.~bt\Sources\Panther. Upload onto Network drive and share the link here for our research.

Answer (score -2):

Error 0x8007025D - 0x2000C
This error occurs if the ISO file's metadata is corrupt.

Please Download another Windows 10 ISO again, and retry installing to Windows 10.

Comment: Actually there are other possibilities already mentioned in comments.

Comment: Yes, I see, just provide the suggestions according to my knowledge, and also, I add comments above to collect information for further troubleshooting.